# Conditional scss or overwrite the varialbles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4

In react state I am passing a list, where and calling component where I want

```
comments: {
                elementLabel: "Comments",
                elementType: 'textarea',
                className: "form-control",
                elementConfig: {
                    placeholder: "comments",
                    name: "comments",
                    id: "comments",
                       },
                value: '',
                rows: "5",
                cols: 5,
                form_value: "",
                validation: {
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                isChanged: true,
                errorMessage: "",
                changed: (event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, "comments"),
                blured: (event) => this.inputBlurHandler(event, "comments")
            },
```

if below value called, than in the class of it I want to set

```
.form-control {
    height: 34px !important;
  } instead of this i want to set `80px`
```

the full class of scss will found here in [style.scss](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-qbewf)
How can I achieve this? 
 If I am trying to add new class rendering it with div than does not make any changes, it overwrites it back.

```
<div className="form-row mb-3">
                                <div className="col-md-12">
                                    <div className="ftm-form">
                                        <Input
                                        className="form-control-height"
                                            {...this.state.comments}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

before changes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eU7.png)
After your chages [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ierFA.png)

Comment: would be better to not have fixed height defined in the first place. And also you shouldn't use important here. But do it this way, if you want a different styling just set a different class. and in your css you set `.form-control.my-super-class { height: 80px !important; }`

Comment: updated question with your suggested changes

Comment: it looks like this is now a general CSS issue and not resolved to your initial question. You can update your CSS or your HTML, depending on how things should look. Or open a new question if you can't solve this issue on your own. but it looks like you can now set the height depending on the state of your app.

Answer (score 1):

First off all, in css you should describe your classes as

```
.form-control {
    height: 34px;

    &.form-control-height {
      height: 80px;
    }
  }
```

And in react code, you are overwriting your className with your state. Refactor your code in a way:

```
<div className="form-row mb-3">
  <div className="col-md-12">
    <Input {...this.state.comments} className="form-control form-control-height" />
  </div>
```

Comment: same issue please check the qusetion updated the screen shots